# My Pdf document is not downloading or opening where as image file is opening after download in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, pdf, download, storage

My Pdf document is not downloading  or opening where as image file is opening after download in flutter.

I have use file picker to pick image files and pdf files and send them to firebase storage.

My image  file is downloading and opening perfectly fine , but unable to  download PDF file  after sending it to firebase storage.

May be it is downloading, but unable to view when clicked on download button.

```
   Future<void> downloadFile(StorageReference ref) async {
    final String url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    final http.Response downloadData = await http.get(url);
    final Directory systemTempDir = Directory.systemTemp;
    final File tempFile = File('${systemTempDir.path}/tmp.jpg');
    if (tempFile.existsSync()) {
      await tempFile.delete();
    }
    await tempFile.create();
    final StorageFileDownloadTask task = ref.writeToFile(tempFile);
    final int byteCount = (await task.future).totalByteCount;
    var bodyBytes = downloadData.bodyBytes;
    final String name = await ref.getName();
    final String path = await ref.getPath();
    print(
      'Success!\nDownloaded $name \nUrl: $url'
          '\npath: $path \nBytes Count :: $byteCount',
    );
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        content: Image.memory(
          bodyBytes,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}``
```

Please suggest me if any changes needed in the above code or any where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter supports opening Images by default, to open pdf's you need to use pdf plugin (dependencies). https://codecarbon.com/top-pdf-widgets-for-flutter/   go through this link, I think **7. pdf_viewer_plugin** suits you for this app.

```
Dependencies:
flutter_full_pdf_viewer: ^1.0.6 # MIT  Licence
```

Create a new file display-pdf.dart and past the below code there.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_full_pdf_viewer/full_pdf_viewer_scaffold.dart';

class DisplayPDF extends StatelessWidget {
  final String pdfPath;
  final String title;

  DisplayPDF(this.pdfPath, this.title);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PDFViewerScaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        path: pdfPath);
  }
}
```

Create a file pdf-utilities.dart and past the below code there.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class PdfUtilities {
  final String pdfPath;
  final BuildContext context;

  PdfUtilities(this.pdfPath, this.context);

  Future<String> prepareTestPdf() async {
    final ByteData bytes = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).load(pdfPath);
    final Uint8List list = bytes.buffer.asUint8List();

    final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final tempDocumentPath = '${tempDir.path}/$pdfPath';

    final file = await File(tempDocumentPath).create(recursive: true);
    file.writeAsBytesSync(list);
    return tempDocumentPath;
  }
}
```

Replace `Future<void> downloadFile(StorageReference ref) async` with this code:

```
Future<void> downloadFile(StorageReference ref) async {
  final String url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
  final http.Response downloadFile = await http.get(url);
  final Directory systemTempDir = Directory.systemTemp;
  final File tempFile = File('${systemTempDir.path}/tmp.pdf');
  if (tempFile.existsSync()) {
    await tempFile.delete();
  }
  await tempFile.create();
  final StorageFileDownloadTask task = ref.writeToFile(tempFile);
  final int byteCount = (await task.future).totalByteCount;
  var bodyBytes = downloadFile.bodyBytes;
  final String name = await ref.getName();  
  final String path = await ref.getPath();
  print(
    'Success!\nDownloaded $name \nUrl: $url'
        '\npath: $path \nBytes Count :: $byteCount',
  );
  final String title = 'Displaying PDF';
  PdfUtilities pdf = new PdfUtilities(path, context);
  pdf.prepareTestPdf().then(writeCounter(await bodyBytes),
        (path) {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => DisplayPDF(path, title),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
Future<File> writeCounter(Uint8List stream) async {
  final file = await _localFile;

  // Write the file
  return file.writeAsBytes(stream);
}
```

Comment: ok thank you let me check and update you. ae you sure no other changes required in the code ?

Comment: final File tempFile = File('${systemTempDir.path}/tmp.jpg'); create one more variable   final File tempFile = File('${systemTempDir.path}/tmp.pdf'); (this is just a example modify it according to your requirement.). .jpg is not the only image format https://blog.hubspot.com/insiders/different-types-of-image-files. what I suggest here is you display a dialog box after downloading and give an user option to open or cancel. This gives you an option to open a pdf or image based on file extension. It can also be done directly without dialog box. This depends on what app you are making.

Comment: for this application I want to download only PDF files, upload only pdf files to  firebase storage.  Ok I will try your logic / code.

Comment: Tried replacing final File tempFile = File('${systemTempDir.path}/tmp.jpg');   to final File tempFile = File('${systemTempDir.path}/tmp.pdf');   and using pdf viewer plugin , but unable to view or download but getting sent to firebase storage.

Comment: You were able to download the file before Right? Use the same code. To View pass the the path to the pdf. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNzAlTO0GNQ Please go through  this video also. Once you are able to download Send the downloaded path to the next screen to view. It will open a new screen to show pdf contents. Make sure you provide a back in appbar (new screen) to go back to the previous screen.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, mistaken I mean to say that I am able to pick the pdf file and just upload to firebase storage. I am unable to download or retrieve. Please help. I ahave been following file picker video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30L5-3eQPK4&t=285s    and the code here  https://www.coderzheaven.com/2019/06/22/firebase-storage-uploading-and-downloading-files-multi-file-picker/. No please help me form here as I am able to download and vie only image files. Help me download pdf files.

Comment: Please reply ASAP as I have to implement in my current project to download and view the pdf file.

Comment: Ok. will try to get it done by tomorrow morning.. Indian Standard Time(IST)..

Comment: Done.. Just pass the path of local file to this class. And it does the rest..

Comment: If you like the answer please mark the answer as selected. I will get some reputation points for it.

Comment: How and where to add your code in my file pcker ad uploadig to firebase code                    https://www.coderzheaven.com/2019/06/22/firebase-storage-uploading-and-downloading-files-multi-file-picker/                                                                                      Anyway thanks for the code I will try this code and update you and check will it work/ not?

Comment: Create a new file display-pdf.dart and add this code completely. In the video you are referring ```youtube.com/watch?v=30L5-3eQPK4&t=285s``` when the down load button is clicked it downloads the ```.jpg`` file and displays it. you have to alter that part. you have to download the file, collect the path and display pass the path to this DisplayPDF.

Comment: Thank you ,pls try to put the code  in my youtube video code only . Anyway I will create a new file display-pdf.dart  and try your suggestion .

Comment: I gave a demo code from my work. But will change it as per your request. Please wait.

Comment: Ok Thanks I am checking at my side

Comment: I am requesting this as I primarily want to pick a pdf file and upload to firebase storage and then, again want to view the uploaded pdf by downloading again.

Comment: Thank you for your cooperation, I am waiting for your modified code actaully, I tried your code in one single .dart file , but unsuccessful. Please try

Comment: Please send the code as promised. Thank you

Comment: ok Can I expect in the morning or afternoon pls

Comment: Hi Vinay eager to see your code and implement at my side as  I have to submit my project with that. Thank you

Comment: @srk2k14, Ya buddy working on it. Please mark my answer as selected and vote. I need some reputation points. not able to even comment now. Used mine on bounty.

Comment: Yes Done can you please me  the code to email id svn_k1@yahoo.co.in, if possible share your email id and phone number too if possible. I will eagerly wait for the complete code or just the modifications in  the youtube video code.. Thank you very much

Comment: Please som body make me achieve  this, I need a download button after sending pdf to firebase storage. I have folloed youtube video tutorial of file picker  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30L5-3eQPK4&t=285s. Please help me from here. I am unable to download pdf file and view here as I am able to download image files.

Comment: Sorry, will help you my pc was not working since yesterday. So couldn't complete. Please give me some time. will finish it.

Comment: Ok I will wait for your email ttoo, if possible mail me also

Comment: Sorry, PC still not working properly. Reinstalling everything might take time. If you are in a hurry, Please look for an alternative. But will work on your issue as soon as it starts working. I sincerely apologies for the inconvenience caused to you. Thank You

Comment: Ok any ways you please work on the downloading issue

Comment: I am still waiting for someone who can answer and fix my issue

Comment: @srk2k14: I have updated the answer, haven't test the code because I don't have firebase account but this should work. Please check and tell.

Comment: @srk2k14: I have updated the answer, haven't test the code because I don't have firebase account but this should work. Please check and tell.

Comment: Ok definitely I will give my feedback. Thanks very much for your efforts Vinay.

Comment: I am getting error at main()  i.e  void main() async {

  runApp(DisplayPDF());
}
saying                                                                                 
 2 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.  Try adding the missing arguments. Open documentation Without main(0 flutter application is not running saying there is main function()

Comment: why are you putting ```DisplayPDF()``` in ```runApp```, it will definitely give you error. youtube.com/watch?v=30L5-3eQPK4&t=285s what ever code is there in this video should be the same. Along with this create two more dart file and past the code as instructed above. Replace ```Future<void> downloadFile(StorageReference ref) async``` with the code given above.

Comment: then total three dart files right? I will give a try again

Comment: Error at " final String title = 'Displaying PDF';
  PdfUtilities pdf = new PdfUtilities(path, context);
  pdf.prepareTestPdf().then(
        (path) {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => DisplayPDF(path, title),
        ),"   saying as undefined name context . please fix it ASAP.  Now I have three dart files including your 2 dart files and main code.

Comment: only error at context  and I have created a local variable LocalFile also.

Comment: Hi I am waiting for somebody to  fix my issue regarding context etc,It should route to  DisplayPDF page and open PDF document.

Comment: I will check and update  you Vinay  once thank you for your support

Comment: Yes I have tried your code with three dart files as discussed yesterday  but when I click on download "Down arrow" Icon it is not directing to DisplayPDF page and not opening my pdf . Please help .Please clear my query whether I have to put tmp.pdf or tmp.jpg at "final File tempFile = File('${systemTempDir.path}/tmp.pdf');" in the youtube video code?

Comment: And my log out put is showing as below:                                                                                  I/flutter (27615): Downloaded ANNEXURE.pdf 
I/flutter (27615): Url: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/upload-image-7c0f4.appspot.com/o/ANNEXURE.pdf?alt=media&token=92d5a8c9-1793-48ea-a1e7-7c0c715c40fb
I/flutter (27615): path: ANNEXURE.pdf 
I/flutter (27615): Bytes Count :: 509447

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225453/discussion-between-vinay-h-p-and-srk2k14).

Comment: Updated code but this should work. If not there is some thing wrong with other part of your code because the file is getting downloaded.

Comment: I am still looking after correct fix or solution to my isssue. Please somebody try to fix it ASAP. I want to download pdf  on click of download button there itself.

Comment: Please somebody help me from here.Just need to download and view the pdf in flutter application. Please fix this issue.

Comment: @srk2k14 Have you done it, or it still pending?

Comment: Done but with a different techinque pdf_flutter as my urls were network urls uploade to fiebase and retrieved firebase. We can check w and see while uploading pdf and even retrieve clearly after uploading using pdf_flutter.. check in pub.dev